# How to show absolute URLs in API endpoint docs with RAML?

Tags: rest, documentation, raml

I'm using [RAML](http://raml.org/) to document my REST API. In the RAML doc, I specify the base URL at the root-level

```
baseUri: http://api.example.org/api/{version}
version: v1
```

Then in the API endpoints section of the doc, I specify their URL relative to this base, e.g.

```
/foo/bar:
    get:
      description: blah blah blah
```

When I run `raml2html` to generate a HTML page from the RAML doc, the relative URL `/foo/bar` is shown in the docs for the API endpoint, but I would prefer to show the absolute URL `http://api.example.org/api/v1/foo/bar` instead, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raml2html` allows using custom templates for the overall documentation wrapper, each resources and each items.

In your case you want to customize the resource template and then use it with the `-r custom-resource.handlebars` parameter.

Comment: are there any examples/tutorial for providing custom templates?

Comment: You can use the existing templates as examples: https://github.com/kevinrenskers/raml2html/tree/master/lib